# How to validate google reCAPTCHA in alpinejs?

Tags: alpine.js

I have a AlpineJS signup form with reCAPTCHA I want to validate reCAPTCHA. In google reCAPTCHA we need to pass some callback function for client side validation. Method inside alpine function is not accessible for reCAPCTHA.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div x-data="alpineFormApp()">
    ...
    Form Input HTML
    ...
</div>

alpineFormApp = () => {
    ...
    other code
    ...
    validateCaptcha(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
}

//Captcha callback funtion
function captchaCallbackFn(response){
    window.alpineFormApp().validateCaptcha(response);
}
```